# Prove it by theory of combination

Tags: combinations

Consider a $100$-sided regular polygon. How can I choose three points from the $100$ points such that they will be the vertices of a right angled triangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The vertices all lie on a circle.  What do you know about right-angled triangles in a circle?